# Django orm: moving selected records from a column to another and save to database

Tags: django, orm

I have the following list:

```
list = [
    "WP1788/1",
    "WP1810/1",
    "WP1810/2",
    "WP1812/1",
    "WP1815/1",
    "WP1818/1",
    "WP1823/1",
    "WP1827/1",
    "WP1828/1",
    "WP1828/2",
    "WP1828/3",
    "WP1828/4",
    "WP1828/5",
    "WP1828/6",
    "WP1837/1",
    "WP1840/1",
    "WP1841/1",
    "WP1855/1",
    "WP1860/1",
    "WP1861/1",
    "WP1863/1",
    "WP1872/1",
    "WP1873/1",
    "WP1873/2",
    "WP1879/1",
    "WP1884/1",
    "WP1888/1",
    "WP1895/1",
    "WP1895/2",
    "WP1906/1",
    "WP1906/2",
    "WP1908/1",
    "WP1908/2",
    "WP1909/1",
    "WP1909/2",
    "WP1913/1",
    "WP1918/1",
    "WP1919/1",
    "WP1919/2",
    "WP1919/3",
    "WP1922/1",
    "WP1928/1",
    "WP1928/3",
    "WP1928/4",
    "WP1928/5",
    "WP1928/6",
    "WP1944/1",
    "WP1944/2",
    "WP1945/1",
    "WP1946/1",
    "WP1947/1",
    "WP1955/1",
    "WP1962/1",
    "WP1965/1",
    "WP1965/2",
    "WP1967/1",
    "WP1969/1",
    "WP1977/1",
    "WP1988/1",
    "WP1991/1",
    "WP1991/5",
    "WP1995/1",
    "WP2002/1",
    "WP2012/1",
    "WP2015/1",
    "WP2017/1",
    "WP2021/1",
    "WP2022/1",
    "WP2024/1",
    "WP2033/1",
    "WP2033/2",
    "WP2044/1",
    "WP2050/1",
    "WP1585/1",
    "WP1585/2",
    "WP1585/4",
    "WP1585/5",
    "WP1585/6",
    "WP1585/7",
    "WP1585/8",
    "WP1585/9",
    "WP1624/103",
    "WP1624/105",
    "WP1624/108",
    "WP1624/109",
    "WP1624/118",
    "WP1624/119",
    "WP1624/120",
    "WP1624/121",
    "WP1624/123",
    "WP1624/129",
    "WP1624/130",
    "WP1624/137",
    "WP1624/145",
    "WP1624/165",
    "WP1624/83",
    "WP1624/85",
    "WP1624/91",
    "WP1624/93",
    "WP1670/1",
    "WP1708/10",
    "WP1708/12",
    "WP1708/13",
    "WP1708/14",
    "WP1708/15",
    "WP1708/17",
    "WP1708/20",
    "WP1708/22",
    "WP1708/26",
    "WP1708/27",
    "WP1708/28",
    "WP1779/26",
    "WP1838/1",
    "WP1844/1",
    "WP1876/1",
    "WP1882/1",
]
```

I would like to select the wps (Wp model) in the database with ID in list, something like:

```
wps_selected = Wp.objects.filter(ID in list)
```

and then copy the value from the column working_hours to the column non_profitable and save it to database. Is that possible using ORM. I know how to do it in SQL but I am still a bit comfuased about using ORM

Comment: Can you share the model?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in a simple for loop:

```
wps_selected = Wp.objects.filter(ID__in=list)

for wps in wps_selected:
    wps.non_profitable = wps.working_hours
    wps.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update in bulk with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Wp.objects.filter(
    ID__in=mylist
).update(non_profitable=F('working_hours'))
```

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* name a variable `list`, it overrides the reference to the [**`list`** builtin function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). Use for example `mylist`.